# JQuery each() populating li or span

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I Cannot seem to get this right. my `.each()` returns all 5 elements but my timing is off. also can't seem to get syntax right to get each element of `.each()`:

```
$(data).find("tr td.Chats").filter(':gt(6)').each(function(){
$('#region3').append('<li></li>');          
    $(this).find('td').each(function(k,v){      
        $('#region3 li').append(
        + '<span class="countyHx">' + (this)(1).innerHTML + '</span>'
        + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: yellow;">' + (this)(1).innerHTML + '</span>'
        + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: red;">' + (this)(2).innerHTML + '</span>'
        + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: green;">' + (this)(3).innerHTML + '</span>'
        + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: orange;">' + (this)(4).innerHTML + '</span>'
        + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: purple;">' + (this)(5).innerHTML + '</span>');
    }); 
});
$('#region3').listview('refresh');

}, 'html');
```

Here is my table data in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/MvHTR/)

UPDATE:

I'm almost there, my listview refresh is not refreshing !

```
$(data).find("tr:has(td.Chats)").each(function () {
                var $li = $('#region3').append('<li></li>');
                var $tds = $(this).find('td');
                $li.append('<span class="countyHx">' + $tds.eq(0).html() + '</span><br>' 
                + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: yellow;">' 
                + $tds.eq(1).html() + '</span>' 
                + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: red;">' 
                + $tds.eq(2).html() + '</span>' 
                + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: green;">' 
                + $tds.eq(3).html() + '</span>' 
                + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: orange;">' 
                + $tds.eq(4).html() + '</span>' 
                + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: purple;">' 
                + $tds.eq(5).html() + '</span>');
            });

        $('#region3').listview('refresh');
```

[image]

Comment: There's no code in that fiddle (JS), also, could you tell us your end goal?

Comment: `this(1)` => this snippet requires `this` to be a function, which it obviously is not.

Comment: are you sure `(this)(1)` or `(this)[1]` or `this`

Comment: Why are you using `.filter()` when you're not filtering, but instead just iterating? That looks like it should also be a call to `.each()`.

Comment: Hospitals and more hospitals... Are people's lives depending on your code? :(

Comment: sorry I used (this)(1) as example... I'm trying to end up with approx 25 <li> with the results of the <tr> formattted via <span>. many of the <td> have style data that I'll also need to modify the span background color.

Comment: @Anthony: needed to filter out a select range of <tr>'s

Comment: @BarclayVision There are **two** calls to `.filter()`. The first actually filters, the second is appending and doing other things - that should *not* be a call to filter. This: `$(data).find("tr td.Chats").filter(':gt(6)').filter(` should be: `$(data).find("tr td.Chats").filter(':gt(6)').each(`

Comment: ok, what is the best way to get individual elements from .each?

Comment: do I need to do .append outside of .each?

Comment: @BarclayVision Inside the inner `.each()` you have a reference to the current `<td>` element stored in `v`.

Comment: Because you're adding spans, not `li`.

Comment: how do you refresh a span? since the span is within the li why will it not refresh all ?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MvHTR/6/

Comment: need the colors to be horizontal not vertical, span seemed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MvHTR/5/

```
$('#tblHospitals').find("tr:has(td.Chats)").each(function () {
    var $li = $('#region3').append('<li></li>');
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    $li.append('<span class="countyHx">' + $tds.eq(0).html() + '</span>' + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: yellow;">' + $tds.eq(1).html() + '</span>' + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: red;">' + $tds.eq(2).html() + '</span>' + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: green;">' + $tds.eq(3).html() + '</span>' + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: orange;">' + $tds.eq(4).html() + '</span>' + '<span style="width: 20%; background-color: purple;">' + $tds.eq(4).html() + '</span>');
});
```

It looks like you want to find all rows that have tds with class=Chats, but then process each row and extract data from each TD manually. You were processing the child TDs instead (which makes it a bit harder than working with each row).

You were also appending the result to every preceding li using the selector `$('#region3 li')` where you just wanted the specific LI you just added.

I used the JQuery syntax for getting the html, but you can use the raw DOM elements if you prefer.

If not please clarify the question.

Comment: something similar, every li will have hospital name, within same li will show color and time only if available, all 5 colors need to appear in the same place within li if available.

Comment: Thats it!! - wow thanks so much, I spend hours just trying to explain what i want and you solve it in minutes...

Comment: You are welcome That's what SO is for (I certainly don't do it for the votes... where did everyone go?) :>

Comment: Added some stuff to the Fiddle... seems to work but not sure where yor data is coming from: http://jsfiddle.net/MvHTR/7/

Comment: Sorry, what is not working? The fiddle shows the current data after extract so appears to have refreshed. Not sure what you actual project is doing... Flying a little blind here now. Need more info.

Comment: moved to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185236/jquery-mobile-span-refresh-within-li